# Как отправлять сообщения в контакте циклом?

Tags: javascript

```
document.getElementById("mail_topic").value = "Hallo!тренирую просто javascript";
document.getElementById("mail_write_field").value = "javascript";
document.getElementById("mail_send").click();
location.replace('http://vkontakte.ru/write6194575?hist=1');`
```

Так можно отправить одно сообщение и вернуться в окно отправки, думал сделать циклом:     отправил, вернулся, отправил ещё. Ничего не работает (как можно сделать, подскажите, пожалуйста).

Comment: Гм... Открыть фрейм - настроить форму на него - отправить сообщение. Повторить. А потом думать, что делать с офигенной кучей фреймов.  
Либо почитать про ajax.

Comment: спасибо,а почему нельзя просто сделать циклом?

Comment: Так я и говорю: добавлять ифреймы циклом). Или циклом аяксом отправлять запросы.

Comment: Я имею ввиду без фрейма, просто в строке браузера прописать этот код в цикле.

Comment: Потому что при смене адреса в адресной строке все запросы прекращаются, насколько я помню. Браузер считает, что вы перешли на другую страницу и обрывает весь js (в т.ч. циклы). про фреймы подскажу - <pre>javascript:(function(){var f = document.createElement('iframe'); document.body.appendChild(f); f.src="javascript:alert('lol');"})();</pre> Можно хоть тут пробовать)

Comment: Имеете в виду, эмулировать нажатия пользователя? Придется каким-то образом ждать ответ сервера о том, что сообщение отправлено и только потом слать следующее сообщение. Проще аяксом, но все равно будет мешать капча.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если делать так, как хотите вы, то нужно:

- создать веб страницу;
- в веб страничку запихнуть фрейм контакта, а именно страницы отправки сообщения;
- в родительский документ втулить указанный JS, только нуна подправить location.replace на аналогичное для фрейма;
- произвести выполнение скрипта.

Даже после всего этого отправляться сообщения в цикле не будут. Как минимум по двум причинам:

1. Нам будет мешать капча.
2. Необходима генерация правильного адреса фрейма, нас интересует это: "write6194575?hist=1", оно будет постоянно меняться.

Ващпе-то ваша задача реализуется с помощью серверных языков, в том числе и php. Так что учите. И желаю вам использовать полученные знания в мирных целях (многие программисты могли бы ломать ПО и веб-страницы, но почему-то этого не делают).

Comment: А можно, пожалуйста, немного кода. Я в JS новичок. И фреймы зачем?